# Developing ASP.net site through VPN

Tags: c#, asp.net, vpn, intranet

I'm developing an ASP.net application intranet for my company. I have been building it through a remote desktop connection to my virtual machine. Now, I want to connect to it through a VPN. The VPN is set up, I'm logged in via my company account,  I can access the company resources, all is good. Problem is when I boot up my solution, I'm given an error from trying to access the PrincipalContext, "The server count not be contacted." "The LDAP server is unavailable." I tried commenting out these lines of code, and am getting errors with accessing entity framework entities. I'm very novice to VPNs and IT-related issues, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related : http://serverfault.com/questions/485909/how-can-i-access-a-local-area-ldap-through-a-vpn

Comment: Depending on the VPN solution you use, IIS might or might not be able to access the corporate information (as IIS is a Windows service running in an isolated session than your user session). Since your company provides you this VPN solution, it must have a support team who can tell you how to configure the things right. That is too specific to your company, and nobody on SO/SF can easily give you help.